# FFT frequency analysis seems to get wrong values

Tags: java, android, audio, fft, frequency-analysis

I saw lots of posts here regards frequency analysis and seemed to help me a lot,
yet I tried to record my voice and print out the frequency and seems like the values has no relation
to what is recorded, tried to lift my voice pitch up and down to see what happens with the frequency values,
but the frequency printed as you can see in the logcat posted, has its own will, probably cause of the background noise :)

Here is the code of how I get the frequency:

```
fftArray = FFT.fft(fftTempArray);

MAX = 0;
int index= 0;
for (int i = 0; i < fftArray.length/2; i++) {   
    if (fftArray[i].magnitudes() > MAX) {
        MAX = fftArray[i].magnitudes();
        index = i;                      
    }
    double freq = index * sampleFreq / fftArray.length;
    System.out.println(freq);
}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
11-12 16:01:40.678: I/System.out(23397): 150.0
11-12 16:01:40.678: I/System.out(23397): 150.0
11-12 16:01:40.678: I/System.out(23397): 150.0
11-12 16:01:40.678: I/System.out(23397): 150.0
11-12 16:01:40.678: I/System.out(23397): 150.0
11-12 16:01:40.678: I/System.out(23397): 150.0
11-12 16:01:40.678: I/System.out(23397): 150.0
11-12 16:01:40.678: I/System.out(23397): 150.0
11-12 16:01:40.678: I/System.out(23397): 150.0
11-12 16:01:41.409: I/System.out(23397): 0.0
11-12 16:01:41.409: I/System.out(23397): 0.0
11-12 16:01:41.409: I/System.out(23397): 0.0
11-12 16:01:41.409: I/System.out(23397): 0.0
11-12 16:01:41.409: I/System.out(23397): 0.0
11-12 16:01:41.409: I/System.out(23397): 0.0
11-12 16:01:41.409: I/System.out(23397): 64.0
11-12 16:01:41.409: I/System.out(23397): 75.0
11-12 16:01:41.409: I/System.out(23397): 75.0
11-12 16:01:41.409: I/System.out(23397): 75.0
11-12 16:01:41.419: I/System.out(23397): 107.0
11-12 16:01:41.419: I/System.out(23397): 118.0
11-12 16:01:41.419: I/System.out(23397): 118.0
11-12 16:01:41.419: I/System.out(23397): 118.0
11-12 16:01:41.419: I/System.out(23397): 118.0
11-12 16:01:41.419: I/System.out(23397): 161.0
11-12 16:01:41.419: I/System.out(23397): 161.0
11-12 16:01:41.419: I/System.out(23397): 161.0
11-12 16:01:41.419: I/System.out(23397): 161.0
```

It stays on this range of values no matter what i do.

Could someone please try to help? 
How can it be that the frequency doesn't change when I make high pitch sounds or different type of noises to the mic?

Comment: Did you convert to polar coordinates? I don't understand what your log output is supposed to be.

Comment: your log is weird, why is it in the loop ?

Comment: What is the library you are using? Your own or one from somewhere else? What is the array that's returned? I don't think you've really given enough information to be able to tell what is wrong (if anything).

Comment: My log is in a loop since I'm recording constantly in my app, so the record is in a loop and it prints out the values..regards the library I'm using, i took it from the web and checked it with several sources, so the issue is not there for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You're converting incorrectly from the FFT index to the frequency in the second to last line of code. It should be:

```
double freq = index * sampleFreq * 2 / fftArray.length;
```

Other than that, your code is fine (as far as I can see). Try isolating the bug by running some test data through your code and some test audio through your microphone. Audacity is a v.useful program to see spectrograms of audio, BTW.

Bear in mind that if your sample rate enforces a limit on the frequencies you're analysing. This could be why your values seem to stay within that range

Comment: Judging by how the OP's for loop runs from 0 to fftArray.length / 2 I assume the transform has not discarded the negative frequencies. In which case they should not be doubling the frequencies.

Comment: the current sample rate from that example is 44100 so it should be ok, i am not sure what it means to double the frequencies. 
I find it quite diffucult to figure out why it happens, tried to take a specific frequency and put it next to the microphone to see the deviation but no luck there...

Comment: @Radiodef you're correct in saying that, but I don't know many transforms that do that. If it did it would technically be an incorrect implementation of a FFT. In either case you would still iterate over the loop fftArray.length/2 times

Answer (score 0):

You may be confusing pitch with the peak of the frequency spectrum.  Although they both have the same dimensional units (Hz), Pitch is a psycho-acoustic phenomena that can be very different from the spectral peak (which is often a much higher and changing overtone of the pitch, sometimes slightly inharmonicity, etc.). Thus, pitch detection/estimation methods are different from just FFT frequency peak estimation.

Comment: Well i might be confusing, Isn't the frequency should be higher if i make a higher sound? since its the vibration of the sound wave per second. I know my pitch changes of course but the frequency should change as well/

Comment: The possible point here would become clear if you plotted the entire frequency spectrum at several points in time.  Just looking at the strongest peak can be misleading.

Comment: @Er85 : No, the peak frequency can go lower what making a higher pitched sound.  The peak may could a very different (much lower) overtone, for instance.